# Raku and the Knapsack

Tags: knapsack-problem, raku

The following is a solution to the knapsack problem and supposed to be my entry to this weeks [perl challenge](https://perlweeklychallenge.org/blog/perl-weekly-challenge-036/). I wonder if this is a good use of dynamic variables or is it too confusing?

I use them so I don't have to put the variables  `$n`, `@things` and `@result` in all the signatures of the multi-subs and carry them through the recursion.

```
sub MAIN()
{
    my @data =
        { thing => 'R', weight =>  1, amount =>  1 },
        { thing => 'B', weight =>  1, amount =>  2 },
        { thing => 'G', weight =>  2, amount =>  2 },
        { thing => 'Y', weight => 12, amount =>  4 },
        { thing => 'P', weight =>  4, amount => 10 }
    ;

    my ( $v, $w, @t ) = knapsack( 15, 5, @data );

    say "Value: $v, Weight: $w";
    say "Taken: ", join ",", @t.map: *<thing>;
}

multi sub knapsack( Int $total-weight, Int $*n, @*things )
{
    my @*results;
    my Int $optimal-value  = my Int $current-value  = knapsack( $total-weight, 0 );
    my Int $optimal-weight = my Int $current-weight = @*results[0].pairs.first({ .value eqv $optimal-value }).key // -1;

    return $optimal-value, $optimal-weight, |gather
    {
        # walk the results and find the good ones
        for ^$*n -> $i
        {
            my %d           = @*things[ $i ];
            my $next-weight = $current-weight - %d<weight>;
            my $next-value  = @*results[ $i + 1; $next-weight ];

            with $next-value
            {
                if $next-weight >= 0 && $next-value == $current-value - %d<amount>
                {
                    take @*things[ $i ];
                    $current-value -= %d<amount>;
                    $current-weight -= %d<weight>;
                }
            }
        }

        take @*things[ $*n - 1 ]
                if $current-value > 0;
    };
}

multi sub knapsack( Int $weight, Int $i where @*results[ $i ; $weight ].defined ) { @*results[ $i ; $weight ] }
multi sub knapsack( Int $weight, Int $i where $i >= $*n ) { 0 }
multi sub knapsack( Int $weight, Int $i where $i < $*n )
{
    my $leftover-weight = $weight - @*things[ $i ]<weight>;
    my $current-value   = knapsack( $weight, $i + 1 );

    my $next-value = $leftover-weight >= 0
        ?? ( @*things[ $i ]<amount> + knapsack( $leftover-weight, $i + 1 ) )
        !! 0;

    @*results[ $i ; $weight ] = ( $current-value, $next-value ).max
}
```